# SQL distinct issues

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table in this format:

```
Screenname|realname|followers|tweet
bob       |jim     |5        |hi
bob       |jim     |20       |hello
tom       |joe     |15       |JOETHECAT
tim       |joe     |16       |TEST
```

I need to write a query that displays each unique screenname along with their realname and totalnumber of followers.

```
Screename realname followers
bob       jim      25
tom       joe      15
tim       joe      16
```

Answer (score 2):

Use GROUP BY by Screename, realname and SUM followers.

```
select Screename, realname, sum(followers) as followers
from your_table
group by Screename, realname
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Select screenname, realname, sum(followers) as followers 
from twitter_users 
group by screenname, realname
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple using group by

```
select Screename, realname, sum(followers) as followers
from your_table
group by Screename, realname
```